# a problem with load image from cache on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage

Here my code

```
UIImage * result = [[UIImage alloc] imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

here my error log

```
> 2009-12-22 17:00:44.137
> DrillDownApp[2061:207] touchesBegan
> from root 2009-12-22 17:00:44.138
> DrillDownApp[2061:207] touchesBegan
> from root at X = 52.000 and Y = 87.000
> at INDEX = 0 2009-12-22 17:00:44.139
> DrillDownApp[2061:207] index = 0
> 2009-12-22 17:00:44.140
> DrillDownApp[2061:207] Begin Load
> Image 2009-12-22 17:00:44.141
> DrillDownApp[2061:207] Load Image
> complete 2009-12-22 17:00:44.142
> DrillDownApp[2061:207] get index = 0
> 2009-12-22 17:00:44.143
> DrillDownApp[2061:207]
> /Users/ragopor/Library/Application
> Support/iPhone
> Simulator/User/Applications/47C3AA6B-4C93-4A17-BF3C-D212D11951F2/Documents/URLCache/P4010143.jpg
> 2009-12-22 17:00:44.144
> DrillDownApp[2061:207] *** -[UIImage
> imageWithContentsOfFile:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance
> 0x3d180b0 2009-12-22 17:00:44.144
> DrillDownApp[2061:207] *** Terminating
> app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
> '*** -[UIImage
> imageWithContentsOfFile:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance
> 0x3d180b0' 2009-12-22 17:00:44.145
> DrillDownApp[2061:207] Stack: (
>     29721691,
>     2449544457,
>     30103611,
>     29673078,
>     29525698,
>     13756,
>     20415,
>     20979,
>     25843,
>     18694,
>     3160730,
>     3143896,
>     397754,
>     29506240,
>     29502536,
>     37812109,
>     37812306,
>     2887683,
>     11024,
>     10878 )
```

Comment: UIImageView * result = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];

this code can resolve my error

Answer (score 0):

imageWithContentsOfFile is a class method. You should use either

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

or

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

[imageWithContentsOfFile](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile:) is a static function that returns a UIImage. No need to alloc an image.

```
UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: thank you Fungus for reply
UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

this code still got some error

Comment: u should call [result retain] along with that